# igraph data manipulation within Shiny reactive

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to process data within Shiny to produce a graph data frame that can be handled by igraph but I am struggling with the nested data transformation.

I ma getting the following error message

"Error in plot.igraph(g3, layout = layout.mds) : Not a graph object"

any idea?

Here is the server

```
library(shiny)
library(igraph)


# Define a server for the Shiny app
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  g4 <- reactive({

  g2 = gtest[gtest[3]==input$article,]
  g2 = g2[order(g2[3],decreasing = TRUE), ]
  g2 = graph.data.frame(g2[1:5,2:3], directed=TRUE)
  return(g2)

 })



  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot

  output$g3plot <- renderPlot({

    #render network graph

    plot.igraph(g4,layout=layout.mds)
  })
})
```

and here is the UI

```
library(shiny)
gtest<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(1:10),c(11:20), c(21:30))

# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(

  # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
  fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel("Articles by similarities"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      
      # Define the sidebar with one input
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("article", "Article:", choice=gtest[1])),
        hr()
      ),

    # Create a spot for the plot
      mainPanel(
      plotOutput("g3plot")  
      )

    )
  )
```

Comment: You should read the article on [reactivity in Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html). `g2` is reactive to `input$article`, but `g3` and `g4` are not listening out for changes to `g2`. Why not place the whole thing in a reactive block?

Comment: Yes I tried that but doesn't work g4 <- reactive({
  g2<-gtest[gtest[2]==input$article,]
  g3 <- g2[with(g2,order(g2[3],decreasing = TRUE)),]
   graph.data.frame(g2[1:5,], directed=TRUE)})

Comment: You have tried to edit your question, but your code has gone through an arbitrary change where you now use `isolate` -- why? The error that you are getting and which you see in my answer as well has nothing to do with Shiny. The object you are passing to `plot.igraph` is not an `igraph` object and hence cannot be handled by `plot.igraph`.

Comment: graph.data.frame(g2[1:5,2:3], directed=TRUE) is not an igraph object?

Comment: If you had read the article I had linked to, you would have understood the issue. `g3` in my code is not an `igraph` object, but `g3()` is. Check that the code in the answer below solves your problem.

Answer (score 6):

There really are quite a lot of issues with your code syntactically, and in several places I cannot understand the logic. I have cleaned up the code so that it is an MWE.

```
library(shiny)
library(igraph)

gtest = data.frame(cbind(Article = c(1:10), from = c(11:20), to = c(21:30)))
runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(    
      titlePanel("Articles by similarities"),
      sidebarLayout(      
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("article", "Article:", choice = gtest$Article)
        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("g3plot")  
        )
      )
    )),

    # Define a server for the Shiny app
    server = function(input, output) {
      g3 = reactive({
        g2 = gtest[gtest$Article==input$article,]
        g2 = g2[order(g2[[3]],decreasing = TRUE), ]
        graph.data.frame(g2[1:5,2:3], directed=TRUE)
      })


      # Fill in the spot we created for a plot

      output$g3plot = renderPlot({
        plot.igraph(g3(), layout=layout.mds)
      })
    })
)
```